# Android file-creation fails

Tags: java, android, io

I use the following code to create a folder "mymir" and a file ".nomedia" (in the mymir-folder) on the sdcard of an android unit. However, somehow it fails with the exception that the folder the ".nomedia"-file is to be placed in dosn't exist. Here's the code:

```
private String EnsureRootDir() throws IOException
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File mymirFolder = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/mymir/");
    if(!mymirFolder.exists())
    {
        File noMedia = new File(mymirFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/.nomedia");
        noMedia.mkdirs();
        noMedia.createNewFile();
    }
    return mymirFolder.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: I am using the same code as you have used and also have given the permission but there is no error and nomedia file is not showing in my folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I SD really there?

```
Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) == true
```

If targeting 1.6+, have you declared

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

?
The exact Exception could help.

Comment: I didn't get an exception on trying to create the dir. It only returned false. However, the problem was the user-permission I didn't have. I just found out, but thank you anyway :-)