# Android: Save image to sd card without view in gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I use this code for save image to sd card :

```
URL url = new URL(downloadPath);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();

int len = 0;
int downloadedSize = 0;

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[G.DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
     downloadedSize += len;
     downloadPercent = (float) (100.0 * (float) downloadedSize / fileSize);
}

outputStream.close();
```

But after save , in gallery is shown

I want save to sd card but not shown in gallery

Comment: What file path are you passing it ?

Comment: I think your solution lies in this ans
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697276/android-nomedia-not-working-for-images)

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria this way : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

Comment: @sush use this ? : sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Comment: i didnt get u. check the link.

Comment: I don't think making file extension to .nomedia will help .

Comment: @Mohammad Does your question says that running this code launches Gallery application?

Comment: Thank you, .nomedia is solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **.nomedia** file inside the folder.

Understand the concept of nomedia file [Link](http://www.techabrel.com/2015/01/how-to-create-nomedia-file-in-android.html)